# Why there is a dash after I type C-c . (period)?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I want to insert a timestamp under `org-mode`. As stated in the official tutorial of org-mode, `C-c .` should be enough for inserting a timestamp.

However, when I type `C-c .`, it shows `C-c .-` and is waiting for one more input. If I then type other keyboards, Emacs says that this command is undefined.

If I start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and type `C-c .`, I get `C-c . is undefined`.

What is going on, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's waiting for more keys, then `C-c .` is a *prefix binding*.

Type `C-h` next (or alternatively `<f1>`), and Emacs will show you what is available under that prefix.

By default (in Emacs 24.5) `C-c .` is indeed bound directly to `org-time-stamp` in `org-mode` buffers; so something in your own config has clobbered that binding, by the sounds of it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I turned the global ede mode on. Now it works fine :)

Comment: @Dan thank you for your remind. Now I've done it.